# Regex to find a range in an ip address

Tags: regex

For example, on my cisco switch I want to find all results with a second octet between 63-255.
So first octet 10.
Second octet 64 - 255 
Third and fourth octet can be any

So it should like this 10.[64 - 255 ].*.*

This where I got to

```
10 \?\ ..* \ ..*
```

Thanks

Comment: Try [`^10\.(6[4-9]|[7-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))\.`](https://regex101.com/r/AcRK2Q/1)

Answer (score 4):

The following regex does what you want ([mandatory regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/Ku33UF/2)):

```
10\.(6[4-9]|[7-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(1?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(1?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])
```

It may look complex (mostly because of its length), but it's actually straightforward. Here's a breakdown:

- `10` matches the first octet which is supposed to be 10
- `\.` matches a dot. Same goes for the other `\.`s
- `(6[4-9]|[7-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])` matches the second octet, making sure it's between 64 and 255 (inclusive) this way:

  - Match a 6 followed by a 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9 `6[4-9]` (numbers between 64 and 69), **or**
  - Match a 7, 8 or 9 followed by a digit `[7-9]\d` (numbers between 70 and 99), **or**
  - Match a 1 followed by two digits `1\d\d` (numbers between 100 and 199), **or**
  - Match a 2 followed by a 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4, which is then followed by a digit `2[0-4]\d` (numbers between 200 and 249), **or**
  - Match a 2 followed by a 5 followed by a 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 `25[0-5]` (numbers between 250 and 255)
- The first `(1?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])` matches the third octet (which can be anything between 0 and 255) this way:

  - Match a digit **optionally** preceded by a 1 and **optionally** followed by another digit `1?\d\d?` (numbers between 0 and 199), **or**
  - Match a 2 followed by a 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4, which is then followed by a digit `2[0-4]\d` (numbers between 200 and 249), **or**
  - Match a 2 followed by a 5 followed by a 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 `25[0-5]` (numbers between 250 and 255)
- The second `(1?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])` matches the fourth octet using the same logic